# How to remove quantity box in Magento 2 product page

Tags: magento2

I want to remove or hide the quantity box in the magento 2 product page, someone know how can I do that? (the quantity box is not relevant for our business)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either do it with CSS which i in no way recommend
Or you can remove it from: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml

Regards!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I assume that I have to add something like:
'<referenceBlock name="" remove="true"/>'
in the xml file. Do you know the name of the qty box block?

Comment: Exactly :-) Which theme are you using?

Comment: I actually see now that the qty box is not build with XML you have to remove it from this file:https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml